# how to check the actual size of archived file without extracting it?

Tags: linux, compression, extract, archive, sparse-matrix

I've got an archive foo.tar.gz(8M of actually size), which contains a large sparse file(around 10G) in it.

My question is, how could I know the actual sparse file size without extracting the archive?

Comment: nice Question but it's better to ask it in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tar ztvf foo.tar.gz
```

would list the contents of the file without extracting.

The `--totals` option causes tar to print on the standard error the total amount of bytes transferred when processing an archive.

```
tar ztvf foo.tar.gz --totals
```

would return the total number of bytes read (essentially the size of the archive after extracting).

If you are looking for a particular file in the archive, say of the *pattern* `FOOBAR`,

```
tar ztvf foo.tar.gz -v --wildcards '*FOOBAR*'
```

would list the matching file(s) that would contain the size.

Comment: the `dry-run` indeed helps, thanks a lot!

Comment: what about windows-OS???

Comment: haven't tried yet since I'm on linux.